# VS2019 - MSBuild SdkResolver fails to run when using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to get started with c# (I've been using VS for C++ without issue) and whenever I try to open a C# Project I get this error:

```
The project file cannot be opened. The SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver" failed to run. Illegal characters in path.
```

The .csprj only has 7 lines!

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried swapping the `"` for `'` but got the same error.

Running VS2019 with `/ResetSkipPkgs` prevents this issue from happening and the project loads fine. However I can't find the source of the issue.

Does anyone else know what could be causing this? I'd like to be able to work on C# projects without running VS via commandline every time!

Comment: Please try to create a new project and test whether the issue persists?

Comment: strangely... i am experiencing this issue.  I recently have edited the PATH, but when I use 'dotnet run . from the "Windows Terminal" app.  everything  works as expected.  it seems to be a VS2019 thing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Does anyone else know what could be causing this? I'd like to be able
> to work on C# projects without running VS via commandline every time!

Not sure what you did to your VS before. Maybe this issue is caused by some third party integration tools, vs extensions, or some VS Settings.

**Suggestion**

Please try the following steps:

**1)** make sure that your VS2019 has installed these two workloads

[image]

**2)** check System Environment Variable **PATH** and make sure that it has value `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` and **no other space keys**.

**Also**, check if you have environment variable **MSBuildSDKsPath**, if so, you should check if its value exists and enter the path to check it. If not, you should modify to use  the address that already exists.

If **MSBuildSDKsPath** does not exist, you should add it and set its value to

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.xxx\Sdks
```

Make sure the path exists under your PC.

[image]

**VERY IMPORTANT**: Don't use quotes in the variable value and finish it with a `\`. So please check every environment and make sure that there are no garbled characters.

**3)** open VS IDE, click menu **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** and enter into installed extensions and then disable any third party extensions to check whether the issue is caused by them.

**4)** Reset all VS settings by **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All Settings** or just run `devenv /Resetsettings`.

**5)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version if there is any updates.

**6)** delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and then test again.

================================================

**Besides**, you can directly add the switch into `/ResetSkipPkgs` into VS icon so that every time when you open VS, it will run the `/ResetSkipPkgs` at the same time.

Right-click on the VS2019 Shortcut icon-->**Properties**-->**Shortcut**

[image]

Add `/ResetSkipPkgs` into the

[image]

Click **Apply** and **Ok** to enable it.

**Note**: when you use it, you should open VS by clicking that icon rather than start it under **VS Installer** which does not support that feature).

If you start VS2019 in Start Menu, you should modify the Shortcut by my function in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

Comment: It was the Path variable! It was missing the dotnet path altogether and there was a blank variable with just spaces in there too that can't of been helping.

Added in the paths you suggested and it all seems to be working fine now, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. for me it was also the Path variable, I had to set it to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.404\Sdks - also, this happened in VS 2019 after getting updates for VS 2022 Preview 3 and also for VS 2019 (I also had the .NET Core Cross platform missing, but it didn't fix it).

Comment: Added the env var `MSBuildSDKsPath` resolved the problem... but the SDK version is explicitly defined... not the lastest...

Answer (score 0):

The two SDK resolvers that ship with Visual Studio and dotnet CLI are: **Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver** and **Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver**.

**Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver** is what resolves “built in” SDKs like **Microsoft.NET.Sdk** and **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web**. It first looks for your dotnet CLI (eg **C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe**)

Here is the error message in my case:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Illegal characters in path.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.EnvironmentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCommandPath>b__0(String p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.EnvironmentProvider.GetCommandPath(String commandName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.DotNetSdkResolver.NETCoreSdkResolver.GetDotnetExeDirectory()
```

You have to check the system variables PATH. Open the **Command Prompt** (**CMD**) and type: **echo %PATH%** and check if there are the Illegal characters in path (")
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291"\bin;`

Open the system variables PATH (for Windows 10 and Windows 8):

- In Search, search for and then select: **System (Control Panel)**
- Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
- Click **Environment Variables**. In the section **System Variables** find the PATH environment variable and select it.
- Click **Edit**.

[The system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D5WU.png)

In my case there were the quotation marks in java_home path:

**JAVA_HOME:** `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291"`

**PATH:** `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

**1)** You can correct the path by using the short path without quotes `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`

[Edit environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/134aV.png)

**2)** Move the following paths `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\` up, save and **restart the Visual Studio**.